# How to use multiple summary writers with `tf.train.Supervisor` for TensorBoard

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I would like to do something similar to the `train_writer` and `test_writer` from the [TensorBoard tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/). But using `tf.train.Supervisor`. I am however not sure how best to go about this.

Pseudo code:

```
train_op = #...
train_summaries = # ...
test_summaries = # ...

config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(
    logdir              = ????,
    summary_op          = ????,
    summary_writer      = ????,
)
with sv.managed_session(config=config) as sess:
    while not sv.should_stop():
        sess.run(train_op)
```

So my question is: **How do I save the `train_summaries` and `test_summaries` do different directories?** E.g. `./logdir/train` and `./logdir/test/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `summary_computed`. The docstring shows how to create custom summary writers. You cannot get the Supervisor to manage it automatically, but it is quite simple. From https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py

```
# Create a Supervisor with no automatic summaries.
sv = Supervisor(logdir='/tmp/mydir', is_chief=is_chief, summary_op=None)
# As summary_op was None, managed_session() does not start the
# summary thread.
with sv.managed_session(FLAGS.master) as sess:
  for step in xrange(1000000):
    if sv.should_stop():
      break
    if is_chief and step % 100 == 0:
      # Create the summary every 100 chief steps.
      sv.summary_computed(sess, sess.run(my_summary_op))
    else:
      # Train normally
      sess.run(my_train_op)
```